# VMWare ESX 3.5 Input/Output Error

Tags: linux, filesystems, vmware-esx

I'm using Vmware ESX Server3.5 for running our Server VMs.

In one of our datastore, the partition is used 100% and Its stopping the VM to power on. /vmfs/volumes/504a6db7-97ab1f09-f958-0024818a4940 117G 117G 0 100% /vmfs/volumes/storage1

When I tried to delete the log file folder or files (17GB), I'm getting an Input/Output Error.

```
[root@hostos alerts]# rm -rf evtAz8721
rm: cannot remove `evtAz8721': Input/output error
```

I'm login as root user and the file has RW access.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance. Senthil.

Answer (score 1):

Use console datastore browser to remove files. It's strongly not recommended to do any actions on VMFS volumes via SSH.

Comment: I got this error when i tried to delete a file from Datastore browser
'General Fault Caused by file /'

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem on an old ESX3.5 installation.
The problem seems to be a full VMFS filesystem.
There is some additional information about this problem in the [VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1011592):

> This issue occurs if the journal file is locked by one of the servers
>   in the cluster, and there is not enough space on the device to release
>   the lock.
>
> To resolve this issue log into the console of each ESX server in the
>   cluster and try to delete a file out of the VMFS volume - this
>   operation will succeed on one of your servers, releasing the lock.